# A project that compiles fine on the command line with maven does not compile in intellij idea 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

As a matter of fact the project compiles just fine with eclipse as well but for some reason IntelliJ is not able to deal with it.

We have other large multi-module projects which load just fine - so I don't think this is a general problem with using maven with intellij.

Anyone else faced similar problems please share ideas on fixing this problem.

I am sorry I cannot post the pom for the project here but in general what I see from the way the pom is structured is that the common dependencies are in a parent pom. If I keep copying some of the dependencies to child modules I can get the compilation to move forward but I still do not get why I need to do this at all.

Comment: It is hard to say anything unless you provide problematic POMs

Comment: @fnt I don't think I can provide the poms - but I find it hard to believe no one else has encountered this problem

Comment: There are some known issues specific to Maven 3 support, IDEA 12 resolved most of them, I'd try 12.1.2 release first with the [Use Maven3 to import project](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/8243/20130426032134.png) option enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the better Maven 3 support it's recommended to use the latest IntelliJ IDEA version (12.1.2 at the moment of this writing). There is an option to [Use Maven3 to import project](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/8243/20130426032134.png) that should be enabled.